# Java FX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to run a timer that moves an enemy ship in my Java FX game. It appears to be working, and the ship is actually at the position that I want it to be at behind the scenes, but the graphics don't reflect that. The enemy ship (nothing else) appears to freeze in one position, when in actuality it is still moving. Is there any way in Java FX to manually refresh the graphics that are displayed so that they reflect the actual positions of objects? I think I might sort of try to brute force it using a timer.

Comment: What does this have to do with the out of bounds exception?

Comment: Post your code, please...

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions are thrown when you try to access a not existing index of an array, the question is even though not a useful one as it currently stands

Comment: There is a multitude of reasons why the ship is not moving. In your FXML file, have you placed the right FXID to your ship object? is the ship connected to the correct event handler?  I think you need to provide more info on what is going on with your code ...

Comment: You're probably blocking the javafx application thread. Use some kind of [`Animation`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html) instead.

Comment: @kabanus If I knew, I wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: @fabian Thanks, I'll try this.